# Mysql like плохо или хорошо?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Есть таблица - миллион строк,
в строке есть поле содержащее определенный текст в кол-ве ~500 символов.
Производиться поиск по этому полю.

Поисковой запрос содержит, как правило, 1 слово (фамилию или название населенного пункта) и ограничен лимитом в 10-20 строк.

Вот запрос для примера:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM persons.person 
 where memo like '%Новгородской%' 
 limit 0, 20
```

> 20 row(s) returned    0,047 sec / 0,000 sec

Вопрос: оправданно ли утверждение "MySql `like` использовать плохо" в данном случае ?

Answer (score 1):

Like - оператор отбора по части поля. Иных средств у самого Мускула, насколько знаю, Вы не найдете. Только какие-либо частичные улучшения, наподобие предложенного [@terantul](/users/11594/terantul) .

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах поля memo попробуйте добавить FULLTEXT.
Подробней [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html)

Comment: Вопрос: оправданно ли утверждение "mysql like использовать плохо" в данном случае ?

Comment: Всё зависит от того устраивает ли Вас результат. Если время отклика и затрачиваемые ресурсы приемлемы для Вас то ничего плохого нет. Хотя для общего развития рекомендовал бы просмотреть разные варианты реализации данной задачи.

Comment: Спасибо, правильно ли я понимаю, что известных "вариантов" всего 4:
1) Like
2) fulltext
3) разбивка на ключевые слова в отдельную таблицу
4) sphinx, lucene

??

Comment: да. Как вариант поищите готовые библиотеки для поиска. Даже если не будете использовать в том варианте в котором предлагают, почерпнёте что то новое/полезное для себя.
UPD. на хабре разбирали LIKE VS FULLTEXT  http://habrahabr.ru/post/25646/

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если производительность и качество поиска устраивает — используйте like. Когда/если того или другого станет мало — переходите на что-то специализированное вроде sphinx.